# C# Process.Start не работает

Tags: c#, cmd, visual-studio-2015, процесс, автозапуск

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/SeppPenner/MoneroMiner
Пытаюсь запустить по стандартному примеру, который также там есть. В итоге: в самом Visual Studio, при отладке - все отлично запускается. Стоит только собрать и попробовать запустить без Visual Studio - окно cmd на секунду появляется, исчезает, и ничего не запускает. В чем проблема? Работать начинает, только если добавить ReadKey, что бы программа ожидала, или запустить миллион окон. А при отладке, всего этого не требуется, все запускается с первого раза.

Comment: Покажите метод Main

Comment: Непонятно, в чём вопрос, какое поведение является желаемым. И неплохо бы увидеть ваш код.

Comment: @Zufir, @A K Зачем видеть мой код? Если достаточно зайти по ссылке, и посмотреть пример. Я код никак не модифицировал. Я решил проблему, и приложил решение ниже.

Comment: Естественно, нужно ждать с помощью `ReadKey` или `ReadLine` или каким-либо другим способом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov На самом деле, ждать тут не нужно. Весь вывод в консоль убран. Проблема совсем не в этом. Process.Start откроет программу и без ожидания.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы запускаете другой процесс из своего, после чего ваш процесс завершается. Очевидно, нужно ждать завершения другого процесса. `var p = Process.Start(...); p.WaitForExit();` Не? Хотя без кусочка вашего кода, это гадание на кофейной гуще. Всегда умиляли такие кадры: "Угадайте, почему мой код не работает. Только я его вам не покажу".

Comment: Говорю в 3-й раз: "Код есть в примере, ссылка выше, не 1 символ не изменен". Вам лень открыть ссылку? Легче мне скопировать и скинуть такой же код? Про WaitForExit знаю, но все работает и без него. Процесс успевает открыться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам отвечу на свой вопрос. Проблема была в оптимизаторе, который удаляет нужные куски кода, после сборки. Отключение оптимизации кода, в настройках проекта - исправило ситуацию!

Comment: Отключение оптимизации - решение проблемы? Мда...

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Да, решение проблемы, самое верное и действенное. Оптимизатор удаляет ненужный ему код. Если человек пишет код качественно и без "костылей" - оптимизатор ничего удалять не будет!